# Running the same frame animation on each onClick call

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, frames

I'm trying to display a frame to frame animations using AnimationDrawable when clicking a `ImageView`. But my animation happens only once when I click the `ImageView`. I'm using xml for the animation.

Animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/scorepopup1" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/scorepopup2" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/scorepopup3" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/scorepopup4" android:duration="100" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/invipopup" android:duration="100" />

</animation-list>
```

Here's my xml for the button and the container of the animation image:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bd"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="checkGem" 
    android:contentDescription="bd"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scorePopup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

checkGem Method:

```
ImageView popup1 =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scorePopup);

popup1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.popup1_animation);
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2 = (AnimationDrawable) 

popup1.getBackground();
frameAnimation2.start();
```

My problem is the animation displays only once, But I want it to animate everytime I click. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a `stop()` call on the `ImageView`'s `AnimationDrawable` background right before the `start()` call:

```
//...
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2 = (AnimationDrawable) popup1.getBackground();
frameAnimation2.stop();
frameAnimation2.start();
```

When you first click the `ImageView` the animation will run but at the end it will find itself in a state where it thinks is still running. In that state, calling `start()` will simply be ignored. The `stop()` method *"resets"* that state and the `AnimationDrawable` will run from the start again.

Comment: Great answer and explanation on its state after a click! +1